# Why doesn't wlan0 get added to the Ethernet bridge at boot?

Tags: networking, network-bridge

I've got a headless Ubuntu box that I'm using as a router+switch+WAP. It's got two Ethernet ports and a Wi-Fi card. `eth0` goes upstream (it's connected to a modem, which is connected to a wall jack); `eth1` and `wlan0` go downstream (clients wanting network|Internet access connect to them). `eth1` and `wlan0` are bridged under `br0`, the effect being that all clients to this box are on the same IPv4 subnet (and the box itself only needs one downstream-facing IPv4 address).

This works pretty well, except that when the machine is rebooted, the bridge comes up with only `eth1` on it—no `wlan0`. As you can see from this copy of `/etc/network/interfaces`, both `eth1` and `wlan0` are specified in a `bridge_ports` line; my understanding is that this should cause them both to be added to `br0` when it's brought up. So what gives?

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth1 inet manual

iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports eth1 wlan0
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type`sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
and then change false to true.
Save the file.
Now in terminal type`sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and remove everything except `auto lo
iface lo inet loopback`
Save the file and then in terminal type`sudo service network-manager restart`

Now restart your system and check.

Hope this works for you